# How to do autodelete the trash items in Gmail as it is moved into it?

Tags: gmail, delete

I am receiving some useless mails every now and then. I have applied a filter for it in my Inbox in Gmail, but it resides in Trash. I also want it to get deleted instantly as it comes into Trash as well.

Please suggest me an automated functionality to do this.

Comment: Why do you want this? Messages in the trash are out of your sight anyway, and they're deleted after 30 days.

Comment: I want that to be deleted without my attention just like filters

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that from the web app, it gets emptied automatically after 30 days. You could do it via IMAP, from a desktop client.

[image]